# Highchart circular heatmap interpolation

Tags: javascript, heatmap

JSFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/hochunang/6dghnfcr/8/

How to plot a circular heatmap. I have try to refer [plotOptions.heatmap.interpolation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.heatmap.interpolation)

```
interpolation: true
```

However, the graph I get have many space, how to fill the gaps and draw it in a circle?
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAxna.png)

Expected Result:
[Expected Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMSBk.png)